# How to make raspberry pi Pico MicroPython Code Encryption?

Tags: encryption, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I wrote a code on Raspberry pico. And I want the codes in this program not to be stolen. What encryption do I need to make so that no one can see it?
The project is very simple. Control of a smart home automation. I spent a lot of effort. I don't want it stolen. What can be done so that they don't pull my codes from raspberry?

Comment: It's doubtful you will ever get an answer to this type of question on stackoverflow. We're here to help you fix your code. You're asking for an education in source encryption. I would recommend doing research. What you want to know isn't just a one-off answer. The solution can range from complicated to incredibly complex based on how far you want to go. However, there is really nothing you can do that can't be undone. If somebody with the right skills wants your code, the best that you can hope for is giving them some level of a struggle to get it.

Comment: Maybe you could make a custom MicroPython with your code inside it.  Start here and learn how to build and extend MicroPython: https://github.com/micropython/micropython  Have fun!

Comment: @aMike That will make things a little more of a headache, but all someone has to do is dump the ROM and RAM and they'll have everything. They don't even have to reverse engineer it cause they can just flash the information, as is, back into the ROM and RAM of all the Pico's they want. Their are a number of steps he could take on top of your suggestion, but they can all be discovered and disabled with a hex editor and time. There is no foolproof way to do this. If it can be made, it can be unmade. It will take a lot of work to even just make it hard to crack.